# Cannot read property x of undefined / KnockOut

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm learning KnockOut for a project and I am trying to bind values from the input to push them into editingUserList. However, my binding function is not working. It seems that inside of it, nor editingUserList or its property userKeyValues are recognized.
I get every time the error " Cannot read property x of undefined ".

```
$(function () {
  debugger;
  var keyValueModel = function (key, value) {
    var self = this;
    self.key = ko.observable(key);
    self.value = ko.observable(value);
  }

  var ConfidentialUsersListModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.userToAdd = ko.observable("");

    self.editingUserList = {
      userKeyValues: ko.observableArray([])
    };

    // (...)
  };

  // binding when a user is selected
  $('#addUser').bind('typeahead:select', function (event, suggestion) {
    var userNameValue = $('#addUser').val();
    // pushing value
    self.editingUserList.userKeyValues.push(new keyValueModel(userNameValue, userNameValue));
    // adding initials of every user
    // setUsersInitials($('.userAddedInitials'), 'userNameShare');
  });
  // apply the model defined above
  ko.applyBindings(new ConfidentialUsersListModel());
})
```

So here is a part of the view :

```
<form>
  <div class="shareSearchBar">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input id="addUser" class="typeahead" placeholder="Ajouter un utilisateur" data-bind='value: userToAdd, valueUpdate: "keyup"' />
  </div>
  <!-- <select data-bind="options: userNameList" class="dropdown"></select>-->
</form>
```

(...)

```
<div class='currentUsers' @*data-bind='visible: editingRoleList.roleKeyValues().length > 0'*@>
    <ul id="confidentialityUsersList" data-bind="template: {name:'userAddedTemplate', foreach: editingUserList.userKeyValues}"></ul>
</div>
<div class="validateSelection">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-save">@Resources.Validate</button>
    <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</!--button>-->
```

Do you have an idea ? I misunderstand something probably and already searched many examples without luck... Thank you

Comment: There seems to be an error in your code - might just be from the snippet though. In the first section at the very end, uou're using `}); }` when you should have `}; })`

Comment: I just checked -you are right the syntax doesn't make sense here, but it was the snippet for example

Comment: You really should try to limit mixing jquery and knockout "-isms". You should use knockout ways of doing things wherever possible and not trying to mix jquery event handling. You really should be using a custom binding here. I'm sure it has been asked here before and you can probably find a full implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery handler is outside of the scope of the viewModel, so `self` is undefined.

```
  var ConfidentialUsersListModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    // ...
    // self goes out of scope at the end of this closure
  };

  $('#addUser').bind('typeahead:select', function (event, suggestion) {
    // self does not exist here
    self.editingUserList.userKeyValues.push(new keyValueModel(userNameValue, userNameValue));
  });
```

Hoist the listener into the viewModel so it can access self

```
  var ConfidentialUsersListModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    $('#addUser').bind('typeahead:select', function (event, suggestion) {
      // self is still in scope
    });

  };
```

Further reading on closures/lexical scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem before. If you show all the javascript code, I can better asses the proble. The errors means that an object has a undefined variable x. Check that first. Next check to see if you have a contructor. If you do then put
a bind function on it(ex.)

```
    function constructerExample() {
        this.x = something;
        this.functionName = function() {
             this.x;   // Javascript thinks this is refering to the functionName instead of the constructor
        }.bind(this); // this bind function fixes it
```